# goJS background layer is not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, gojs

I am using goJS code that is exactly same as this link page
http://gojs.net/temp/swimBands2.html

It looks nice when the node is simple, but when it goes with lot of data binded inside each node, it seems the header can't be displayed. I must zoom out to able to see it.

Can someone help me what i must to do?

I modify the code to be below

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("VerticalBands",
                $(go.Part, "Position",
                        {
                            isLayoutPositioned: false,  // but still in document bounds
                            locationSpot: new go.Spot(0, 0, 0, 16),  // account for header height
                            layerName: "Grid",  // not pickable, not selectable
                            itemTemplate:
                                    $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
                                            new go.Binding("opacity", "visible", function(v) { return v ? 1 : 0; }),
                                            new go.Binding("position", "bounds", function(b) {b.position.y+= 30;return b.position; }),
                                            $(go.TextBlock,
                                                    {
                                                        stretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal,
                                                        textAlign: "center",
                                                        wrap: go.TextBlock.None,
                                                        font: "bold 11pt sans-serif",
                                                        background: $(go.Brush, go.Brush.Linear, { 0: "lightgray", 1: "whitesmoke" })
                                                    },
                                                    new go.Binding("text"),
                                                    new go.Binding("width", "bounds", function(r) { return r.width; })),
                                            // for separator lines:
                                            //$(go.Shape, "LineV",
                                            //  { stroke: "gray", alignment: go.Spot.Left, width: 1 },
                                            //  new go.Binding("height", "bounds", function(r) { return r.height; }),
                                            //  new go.Binding("visible", "itemIndex", function(i) { return i > 0; }).ofObject()),
                                            // for rectangular bands:
                                            $(go.Shape,
                                                    { stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0 },
                                                    new go.Binding("desiredSize", "bounds", function(r) { return r.size; }),
                                                    new go.Binding("fill", "itemIndex", function(i) { return i % 2 == 0 ? "white" : "lightgray"; }).ofObject())
                                    )
                        },
                        new go.Binding("itemArray")
                ));
```

I modify the locationSpot to be new go.Spot(0,0,0,-8), the header is going down however the position of the node remain the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the **Part** that holds the "bands" is in the "Grid" **Layer**, and parts that are in that layer are *not* included in the **Diagram.documentBounds**, so users (by default) cannot scroll beyond the document bounds.

There are several possible solutions, depending on what you want to allow your users to do.

You could set **Diagram.scrollMode** to `go.Diagram.InfiniteScroll`, which allows users to scroll wherever they want.  But I don't know if you want to allow that -- users might get lost.

Or, you could modify the "Grid" layer:

    `myDiagram.findLayer("Grid").isBoundsIncluded = true;`

so that parts in that layer are automatically included in the **Diagram.documentBounds**.  If you have anything else in that layer, that might or might not be desirable.

Or, you could put that "VerticalBands" Part in a normal layer and make it not pickable or selectable:

          `layerName: "Background",
          selectable: false,
          pickable: false,`

This is less desirable if you are using the "Background" layer for holding other parts.